# Solidity PRNG with future block hashes: reasonable secure?

Tags: solidity, security

I would like someone to tell me if I am neglecting serious security concerns here. I Am trying to create a Solidity slot machine where hash puzzles (leading zeros) are used to get various jackpots. However, I can't just use a nonce as someone could test nonces offchain and submit the winning one first try. So I've been looking into PRNGs. And I found future blockhashes to be a solid idea as it's very unlikely a miner will be the creator of each and every block in a sequence. The code bellow is a quick simple example of logic for a lottery contract where users submit guesses that must "vest" a number of blocks before they can be checked for a win.

```
    contract Lottery{

    uint128 difficulty;
    uint128 immutable public BLOCK_VEST_PERIOD;
    mapping(address => guess) entry;

    struct guess{
        bytes32 guess;
        uint256 vestEnd;
    }

    constructor(uint128 _vestPeriod, uint128 _difficulty){
        BLOCK_VEST_PERIOD = _vestPeriod;
        difficulty = _difficulty;
    }

    function submitEntry(uint128 _x)external{
        entry[msg.sender] = guess(
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_x)),           //guess is stored as the hash of the number entry
            block.number + BLOCK_VEST_PERIOD
        );
    }

    /// @dev returns true if entry is a winner
    function claimEntry()external returns(bool){
        require(block.number - entry[msg.sender].vestEnd < 256, "cannot claimEntry if more than 255 blocks have passed");
        require(block.number >= entry[msg.sender].vestEnd, "must wait a few more blocks for vesting to end. For security reasons");
        bytes32 hash = entry[msg.sender].guess;
        for(uint128 i = 0; i < BLOCK_VEST_PERIOD; i++){
            hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
                hash,
                blockhash(i)
                ));
        }
        return hashPuzzle(hash);
    }

    function hashPuzzle(bytes32 _entry) public returns(bool){
        /// @dev will return true if hash's leading 0s >= difficulty
    }

}
```

As far as I can tell the only way to cheat this system would be to have control of every block or at least the last block as a miner could discard it if unfavorable to get a second chance. However, this seems to be a negligible advantage in practice, especially if a hash puzzle is sufficiently difficult. Please let me know if I am wrong about this.

Comment: It doesn't look bad. The problem with your question is that there's no way I'm gonna say it is reasonable secure. If I need something secure I'd probably use an oracle.

Comment: This answer has some details on using block hash as a source of randomness: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/95083/68501 I don't think this is a duplicate question since OP here is also demonstrating code and looking for feedback